# Should I include journalistic articles in my CV?

Tags: publications, cv

I have written a couple of articles for two different daily newspapers. In them, I have discussed the issues of my academic field. Should I include these articles in my CV?

If so, under what title? Is press release appropriate? What is the most common and accepted term?

Comment: What is your background and where are you sending this CV?

Comment: @Penguin_Knight I am doing my 4th semester in Tourism management. I like research and have conducted some up to now. Besides I have written 2 articles about tourism in 2 different. news papers. I am sending my resume to different professors to get to know me. I gonna continue my studies by PhD..

Comment: I would list it under *Outreach*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have written a couple of articles for 2 different daily newspapers. In them, I have discussed the issues of my academic field. Should I include them in my CV?

Yes, certainly, as long as you clearly separate them from your academic publications.  Strictly speaking, they are form of publication, so it wouldn't be lying to list them together with your research papers under a vague enough title, but this would be a very bad idea.  It would come across like you are trying to make your publication list look longer by inflating it with non-academic publications.

[If the newspaper articles had nothing at all to do with your academic work, then mentioning them probably wouldn't make sense.  However, it sounds like they do.]

> If so, under what title? Is press release appropriate? What is the most common and accepted term?

Definitely not press release, since a press release is something else: it's a document given to journalists to inform them about a possible story they could write about.  Occasionally newspapers publish lightly edited versions of press releases, without gathering much more information, but this is considered bad reporting.

I don't think there's a clear standard for how to list this information.  You could list it in several ways: outreach, other publications (if you have a "scholarly publications" section, say), writing for the general public, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I am very impressed that you wrote articles about academia that got published by daily newspapers.  I think that information is well worth including on your CV.

In terms of what to call it: I don't think there are any codewords here, at least none that will be reliably decoded by your entire intended audience.  Rather, just clearly identify what you've done, e.g.:

**Articles published in *Daily Xer:*** Title1, date1; Title 2, date 2;
**Articles published in *City Y Times***: Title3, date3

If you feel like your readers might not know that the Daily Xer or the City Y Times is a daily periodical, you should include that information as well.

In terms of where to put it on your CV: well, think about in what way writing these articles will be impressive and valuable to readers of your CV.  Does it show off your high quality writing skills?  Does it show your willingness and ability to communicate technical or insider issues to a very broad audience?  And so forth.  Once you figure out what is the "primary virtue" demonstrated by this activity, you will know where to put it in your CV (perhaps with a section of its own title, but the title should indicate to the reader how you answered the above question).

Comment: thanks for your compliment and really thanks for your answer. The titles are: **The next Iranian Cabinet and tourism** and **The first obstacle to developing tourism in Iran**

Answer (score 3):

I definately think that you should add them to your CV, but, as other have mentioned, under a separate heading from you academic publications. My suggestion is to use the heading **Popular science articles** for these (if all of them are indeed science), or **Newspaper articles** for something more general. I've seen both of these used on CVs. "Press release" would not be suitable to use.

The ability to express scientific results in layman's language is clearly valuable (both inside and outside of academia), so generally I see such an addition as a plus on the CV.

Comment: +1 for _The ability to express scientific results in layman's language is clearly valuable_. Indeed it is!

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a standard ,unless such articles are commonplace in the specific field (e.g. journalism). I definitely think it is worth adding such materials to a CV since they indicate activity. You need to think twice, however, whether or not they provide a positive aspect when you use your CV. Suggestions for appropriate headers could be many. your suggestion sounds good., you could consider something like "Scientific debate articles" or something more descriptive that encapsulates their contents.